# Problems with matplotlib FuncAnimation and Gtk Button

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk

I have some unexpected problems with a callback of a gtk button.

The idea was to create a notebook and inside of it I have two plots using matplotlib and a gtk button to start the animation plot. The problem started when I clicked on gtk button. When I clicked the callback function was called, but the code didn't run the called function "animate" and I don't know the exactly reason.

In another situation, I call the function "animate" after the notebook was added on the gtk window and the animation worked perfectly.

What I want is to know how to start the FuncAnimation of matplotlib only when the user click on gtk button.

Here is my code:

```
import gtk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas

def callbackDelay(widget, a, f):
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, a.animate,interval=1000)   

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        global f
        self.p = 3
        f = plt.figure()
        c = f.add_subplot(211)
        b = f.add_subplot(212)
        xInit = range(0,1000,1)
        yInit = [0] * 1000
        self.line = c.plot(xInit, yInit, '-')
        c.axis([0,200,0,500])
        self.line1 = b.plot(xInit, yInit, '-')
        b.axis([0,200,0,500])

    def animate(self,i):
        global canvas
        q = range(0,10+self.p,1)
        w = range(1,11+self.p,1)
        self.line[0].set_data(q,w)
        self.line1[0].set_data(q,w)
        canvas.draw()
        self.p = self.p + 10

win = gtk.Window()
win.connect("destroy", lambda x: gtk.main_quit())
win.set_default_size(200, 200)
win.set_title("Animation plot with GTK")

notebook = gtk.Notebook()
label = gtk.Label("test")

vbox = gtk.VBox(spacing=6)

#Gtk Button
button = gtk.Button()
button.set_label("init")

a = test()
canvas = FigureCanvas(f)  # a gtk.DrawingArea

button.connect("clicked", callbackDelay, a, f)

win.add(notebook)
vbox.pack_start(button)
vbox.pack_start(canvas)
notebook.append_page(vbox, label)
win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
def callbackDelay
```

you are calling *a.animate* without parentheses. Try:

```
a.animate(10)
```